# how to use google bar chart with spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, spring, velocity, google-visualization

**what should be controller and how i can get my db values here dynamically**
following is the google chart api link which i want to implement

[google chart api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#examples)

html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Javascript

---

```
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population',],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
    chartArea: {width: '50%'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: One way is to make an ajax query to a server resource that query DB and return the values (eg. in JSON). You could then use that when calling the chart api